# Capture the change made to field through javascript

Tags: jquery

Here is a background of the issue i am facing.

I have Visualforce page(Salesforce) which has a lookup field.

A lookup field is group of hidden fields, one normal input field and image with a href which opens up a popup for users to select. Each selected value has 2 values

1. The name of the selectedvalue
2. The id of the selected value.

The name gets stored in the non hidden input field and is gets stored in a hiddenfield ending with lkid. The Html looks like this

```
    <div id="leadConversionPage:leadConversionForm:pBConvertLead:pbSectionLeadSection:pbsiAccountName:optableAccount" style="position:relative">
//Below hidden field stores the id
<input id="leadConversionPage:leadConversionForm:pBConvertLead:pbSectionLeadSection:pbsiAccountName:accountLookup_lkid" type="hidden" value="001i0000008OJ9R" name="leadConversionPage:leadConversionForm:pBConvertLead:pbSectionLeadSection:pbsiAccountName:accountLookup_lkid">
<input id="leadConversionPage:leadConversionForm:pBConvertLead:pbSectionLeadSection:pbsiAccountName:accountLookup_lkold" type="hidden" value="Abbott Insurance" name="leadConversionPage:leadConversionForm:pBConvertLead:pbSectionLeadSection:pbsiAccountName:accountLookup_lkold">
<input id="leadConversionPage:leadConversionForm:pBConvertLead:pbSectionLeadSection:pbsiAccountName:accountLookup_lktp" type="hidden" value="001" name="leadConversionPage:leadConversionForm:pBConvertLead:pbSectionLeadSection:pbsiAccountName:accountLookup_lktp">
<input id="leadConversionPage:leadConversionForm:pBConvertLead:pbSectionLeadSection:pbsiAccountName:accountLookup_lspf" type="hidden" value="0" name="leadConversionPage:leadConversionForm:pBConvertLead:pbSectionLeadSection:pbsiAccountName:accountLookup_lspf">
<input id="leadConversionPage:leadConversionForm:pBConvertLead:pbSectionLeadSection:pbsiAccountName:accountLookup_lspfsub" type="hidden" value="0" name="leadConversionPage:leadConversionForm:pBConvertLead:pbSectionLeadSection:pbsiAccountName:accountLookup_lspfsub">
<input id="leadConversionPage:leadConversionForm:pBConvertLead:pbSectionLeadSection:pbsiAccountName:accountLookup_mod" type="hidden" value="1" name="leadConversionPage:leadConversionForm:pBConvertLead:pbSectionLeadSection:pbsiAccountName:accountLookup_mod">
<span class="lookupInput"> // Below input stores the name
<input id="leadConversionPage:leadConversionForm:pBConvertLead:pbSectionLeadSection:pbsiAccountName:accountLookup" class="accClass" type="text" size="20" onchange="getElementByIdCS('leadConversionPage:leadConversionForm:pBConvertLead:pbSectionLeadSection:pbsiAccountName:accountLookup_lkid').value='';getElementByIdCS('leadConversionPage:leadConversionForm:pBConvertLead:pbSectionLeadSection:pbsiAccountName:accountLookup_mod').value='1';" name="leadConversionPage:leadConversionForm:pBConvertLead:pbSectionLeadSection:pbsiAccountName:accountLookup" maxlength="255" style="opacity: 0.1; width: 250px;">
<script>
<a id="leadConversionPage:leadConversionForm:pBConvertLead:pbSectionLeadSection:pbsiAccountName:accountLookup_lkwgt" class="accClass" title="Account Name Lookup (New Window)" onclick="setLastMousePosition(event)" href="javascript:%20openLookup%28%27%2F_ui%2Fcommon%2Fdata%2FLookupPage%3Flkfm%3DleadConversionPage%253AleadConversionForm%26lknm%3DleadConversionPage%253AleadConversionForm%253ApBConvertLead%253ApbSectionLeadSection%253ApbsiAccountName%253AaccountLookup%26lktp%3D%27%20%2B%20getElementByIdCS%28%27leadConversionPage%3AleadConversionForm%3ApBConvertLead%3ApbSectionLeadSection%3ApbsiAccountName%3AaccountLookup_lktp%27%29.value%2C670%2C%271%27%2C%27%26lksrch%3D%27%20%2B%20escapeUTF%28getElementByIdCS%28%27leadConversionPage%3AleadConversionForm%3ApBConvertLead%3ApbSectionLeadSection%3ApbsiAccountName%3AaccountLookup%27%29.value.substring%280%2C%2080%29%29%29">
</span>
<select id="someList" class="accSelectandlookup" >
</div>
```

Whenever the name changes the id also changes. When the name changes i need to capture the id and add them into a select

The name and id of the lookup is accountLookup, to get the name i can search for all inputs ending with accountLookup. I could have multiple lookups in my form, but i need only the name and id of this lookup which has accountLookup in its name/id to be appended in select.

Here is the jquery  i have done till now with the help of some great people in SO.
The issue i am facing is i am not getting the id value. Its blank

```
 $('input[id*="accountLookup"]').change(function() {
        var accid ='';
        //Loop through all the textboxes and find the one  with lkid
        $.each(['up_lkid'], function(i,element) {
                accid = getInputValue(element); // Get the value of the inputbox ending with lkid
                alert('llllll' + accid);
        });                
        var accname= $(this).val();

        //Get the closest div and find for an elemnet which has class of accSelectLookup
        var selects = $(this).closest('div').find('.accSelectandlookup') ;

       //Check if the accid is already present in the selectoptions and if not then add  
       if (!selects.find('option[value="' + accid + '"]').length) {
        selects.append('<option value="' + accid + '">Attach to Existing : ' + accname + '</option>');
        }

    });
    function getInputValue(endWith) {
         return $('input[id$="' + endWith + '"]').val();   
        }

  });
```

Comment: i tried something like this $('input[id$="accountLookup_lkid"]').change(function() {
         alert($(this).val());
         accid = $(this).val();
         alert('Value of accid in _lkid search' +accid);
         });. But it wouldnt get into method at all

Comment: can u create a jsfiddle